# I would like each route in Emberjs to have its own page, when i have multiple routes they all show the content in the same page

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a quick question Here, I am new to Ember and it looks really exciting, I would like to have multiple routes in my web application, but when I click on a route it redirects the outlet to ONLY this NEW page "route", I don’t want the old page + content of the new page..

Any Ideas how to do that?

Thanks

Omar Mostafa

Comment: Can you show your router.js?

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to versions 1.13 through at least 3.x.

For every route you create with `ember generate route myroutename` you can generate what is called the index of that route:

```
ember generate route myroutename/index
```

An index route is a place to put content that should not show up on child routes.

You can read more about Index Routes in the [Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes).